# Merging rows but maintaining separate columns

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to aggregate data from multiple tables into a single table - please can anyone help?

I have a large number of "history data" tables, each with 2 columns: Timestamp (bigint, unix milliseconds) and Value (double).

I'm trying to collect data from multiple tables, and for each table, calculate the maximum value each day.

My query so far is as follows:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp/1000)) AS Date, 
CASE WHEN Source = 'Meter 1' THEN MAX(Value) ELSE '' END AS 'Meter 1',
CASE WHEN Source = 'Meter 2' THEN MAX(Value) ELSE '' END AS 'Meter 2',
CASE WHEN Source = 'Meter 3' THEN MAX(Value) ELSE '' END AS 'Meter 3'
FROM 
(
    SELECT  'Meter 1' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 1>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Meter 2' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 2>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Meter 3' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 3>
) AS data
GROUP BY Source, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp/1000));
```

If I GROUP BY only DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp/1000)), I see results only from meter 1. By grouping by Source as well, I see all of the results, but the dates are not aggregated, for example:

```
Date        Meter 1     Meter 2     Meter 3
2019-12-11  26       
2019-12-12  27       
2019-12-13  28       
2019-12-14  29       
2019-12-15  30       
2019-12-16  31       
2019-12-17  31       
2019-12-11              18   
2019-12-12              18   
2019-12-13              18   
2019-12-14              22   
2019-12-15              22   
2019-12-16              22   
2019-12-17              22   
2019-12-11                          3747
2019-12-12                          3784
2019-12-13                          3819
2019-12-14                          3847
2019-12-15                          3875
2019-12-16                          3908
2019-12-17                          918
```

I've read a few related questions but I can't figure it out. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm not sure what extra info I can provide that would be any help?

Comment: @phil76 As stated in the link you should provide the SQL commands which create the tables, then the example data you want to operate on and the result set you want based on the input example data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided test data, however let's try this

```sql
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp/1000)) AS Date, 
MAX(if(Source = 'Meter 1', Value, 0)) AS 'Meter 1',
MAX(if(Source = 'Meter 2', Value, 0)) AS 'Meter 2',
MAX(if(Source = 'Meter 3', Value, 0)) AS 'Meter 3'
FROM 
(
    SELECT  'Meter 1' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 1>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Meter 2' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 2>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Meter 3' AS Source, TIMESTAMP AS Timestamp, VALUE AS Value
    FROM    <table name 3>
) AS data
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Timestamp/1000));
```

Comment: Thanks to you both - I'll try this suggested query tomorrow and confirm whether it works. If not, I'll provide test data and relevant table creation commands.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey
Thanks very much, your suggestion works perfectly. It seems that using IF rather than CASE does the trick:

```
Date            Meter 1     Meter 2     Meter 3  
2019-12-11      26          18          3747
2019-12-12      27          18          3784
2019-12-13      28          18          3819
2019-12-14      29          22          3847
2019-12-15      30          22          3875
2019-12-16      31          22          3908
2019-12-17      31          22          3918
```